# R: make column with a sequence of letters for all values in another column greater than threshold

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a multi-column dataframe with one of the columns columns called `number`. I also have a vector called `threshold` holding a single numerical value.

```
df <- data.frame(number = c(1,2,3,5,1,2,3,7,3,5,7,3,6,7))
threshold <- 5
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
   number
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       5
5       1
6       2
7       3
8       7
9       3
10      5
11      7
12      3
13      6
14      7
```

I want to create a new column called `passed`, with `NA` in rows in which `number < threshold` and **sequential** letters of alphabet in rows with  `number >= threshold`. (sequential - starting with the letter `a` at the top of the dataframe). It will look like this:

```
   number passed
1       1   <NA>
2       2   <NA>
3       3   <NA>
4       5      a
5       1   <NA>
6       2   <NA>
7       3   <NA>
8       7      b
9       3   <NA>
10      5      c
11      7      d
12      3   <NA>
13      6      e
14      7      f
```

I would like to not use a loop here, if possible.

Comment: What would happen when you have 1000s of rows i..e after you run out of letters length 26.  Try `library(data.table); setDT(df)[number >= threshold, passed := letters[.I]]`

Comment: @akrun - I know that there will be never more than 26 of cases above threshold because of the nature of my data. Your solution works. Could you explain it? what does ```:= letters[.I]]``` do?

Comment: With data.table, the syntax is `dt[i, j, by]`  here the above code, uses the `i` and `j` part i.e. `i` with logical exrpession `number >= threshold`, j `letters[.I]` where .I is the row index, which is assigned (`:=`) to created the passed column.  All others rows will be NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[number >= threshold, passed := letters[.I]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it in base R, and you know that you will have less than 26 (the length of the alphabet) to fill in, you could consider something like this...

```
df <- data.frame(number = c(1,2,3,5,1,2,3,7,3,5,7,3,6,7))
threshold <- 5
df$number <- df[order(df$number), ]
df$passed <- NA
N <- length(df$passed[df$number>=threshold])
df$passed[df$number>=threshold] <- LETTERS[1:N]
```

If you want, you can then force this back into the original ordering of rows.